# AJAX calls to web service with HTTPS protocol

Tags: ajax, https

I plan to use https to build a website. After the user logs in, s/he is directed to a dashboard. The dashboard will be developed using javascript and html5. What are the thing I need to keep in mind when I make ajax calls using SOAP to a web service while using https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important things:

- always use the same domain name, otherwise browser will throw cross domain errors,
- always use https protocol for every ajax request, so browser won't get [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) errors.

On the server side check for `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` HTTP header, to be sure that the request came as AJAX, not standalone GET/POST request. This is only difference.

With AJAX request browser will send the same cookies value as in the any other request, so you can surely check user session with it.